# is it possible to use javascript var i= [["j.php?i="+input]]; to send to php?

Tags: javascript, php

I am new and just doing practices i just did:
`var i= [["j.php?i=1"]];` and it sent value to php and prints but when i want some input from user it does nothing. For example:

file j.js

```
var input = "hello";
var send= [["j.php?i="+input]];
```

and in j.php

```
<?php
$e=$_GET['i'];
echo $e;

?>
```

Any idea or i am totally wrong? I am trying to have some variation. And i really did with `window.location.href`. But I just want to know how to do in this way var send= [[]]. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** 
your question is not very clear, maybe try this:

```
var input = "hello";
var url   = "/j.php?i=" + input;
var send  = [[url]];
```

But, it's not clear to me what you want to do with your `send` variable...

**Original**

You have to send the data to the server either using a a tag (GET method), a form (POST method) or an Ajax request (any Http verb):

```
<!-- Here you give a unique id to your link -->
<a id="link" href="">your link</a>

<script>
    var i = "Hello";
    // wait for page to be loaded
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
      // change the href attribute of the link with the id equal to 'link'
      // with whatever data contained in the i variable
      // this is done after the page is loaded
      document.getElementById("link").href = "/j.php?i=" + i;
    });
</script>
```

Then, when you just click the link, it will send the variable named `i` containgin the value `Hello` to your php page.

You could also do it in this way:

```
<a id="link2">your link</a>
<script>
    var i = "HELLO";
    // wait for page to be loaded
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
        // here we are telling javascript to change the url 
        // in the browser when the user clicks the link
        document.getElementById('link2').onclick = function() {
            window.location = '/j.php?i=' + i
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can't i do in var send= [["j.php?i="+input]]; bcz when i do like var send= [["j.php?i=1"]]; it does happen... but not var send= [["j.php?i="+input]];???

Comment: What are you doing with the `send` variable? It seems from your code that you are just assigning a value to this variable, but your are not using it anywhere. Have you tried `var url = "j.php?i=" + input` then `var send = [[url]]`